# ClickOnce application deployment issue for new update

Tags: caching, clickonce

I have a clickOnce application which is deployed as "**Start the Application from the Web or a Network Share**". So, fist time a user try to start the application, it will be downloaded and installed to an application cache on the local computer. My problem is that every time I do a release, I update the new files to the network share. But whenever user try to hit the URL, clickOnce will start the application from the cache instead of downloading the new version. I can go for two solutions:

1. Every time user closes the application on local system, cache should
   be deleted.
2. If there is a way to get notification of new update
   even if application is deployed as "**Start the Application from the
   Web or a Network Share**" and next time it will delete the cache to
   download new files.
3. Any other solution apart from above two will be
   helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you publish that the Publish version is being incremented. I always check the box "Automatically increment revision with each publish".

If you make changes and deploy with the same version, click once will not update. Hope this helps.